# Can I use the Negative Binomial distribution to calculate the max number of trials where I have less than X fails with some confidence?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Thank you in advance for any help.

I am trying to compute the maximum number of times I should expect to attempt a Bernoulli trial to keep my number of fails (with probability of failing $p$) under some threshold $T$ with confidence probability $\lambda$. I know I can use the Negative Binomial distribution to calculate the number of trials to achieve $T$ fails with confidence probability $\lambda$, but is there a way I can reshape my definitions to answer my inverse problem. Can I argue that if I have $\lambda$ probability that I will achieve my $T-1$ failure in $N$ trials (as calculated from Negative Binomial Distribution), that with the same $\lambda$ probability, I expect to be under $T$ failures if I make $N$ attempts? Are those equivalent statements?

For example, I have a chance of failing $p=0.1$. I want to avoid failing more than 5 times. How many times do I expect to be able to attempt the trial (i.e., how many successes do I anticipate) before I have to stop to avoid failing the fifth time and I want to have 75% confidence that this will be the case?

If this is not something I can solve easily by manipulating the Negative Binomial Distribution, could you please also give indication of how to implement your suggestion using R or scipy (i.e., negative binomial distribution is qnbinom(lambda, p, r) in R) , as I'm not asking this question solely for theory.

For what it's worth, I am indifferent to whether your suggested method calculates for failures strictly exceeding T or for meeting or exceeding T, whatever is easier. I can make my overall model definition work with either.

P.S. using "confidence probability" to distinguish between the probability associated with each Bernoulli trial and the overall probability of my estimate of trials will give the desired threshold.